# Did anyone resolve this issue in ng-charts 2

Tags: angular5, ng2-charts

https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/835

I have a multi Axis chart and one I click on some point I get all active points per this value. I am using the chartClick event as per the documentation.

For example: I have 4 lines. For year 2000 I click on the point of the first line. But I get an array of active points that contains 4 active points.

I want to know on which of the active points I have clicked, and not get all the 4. Or to get just the specific active point I have clicked on instead of array of all four.

How it can be done?

Comment: are you using the 'chartClick' event function as per https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/

Comment: yes, chartClick is returning all active points, but I need to kno which active point is clicked

Comment: I have a feeling this has something to do with `interaction types`. You might want to change it from `x` to `nearest` or something...